# Firefox has problems with flex and container with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox, overflow

I have done a small [codepen](https://codepen.io/destroy90210/pen/jZjjmG) do demonstrate my problem.

In chrome it works like expected, but in firefox the overflow:hidden styling  seems not to work. It stretches my content over the whole page.

You can comment out the innerHTML in the js-section, that you see that the layout works without content.

I also played around with min-height: 0, but without any result.

html

```
<div class="l-page">
    <header class="page-header"></header>
        <main class="page-content">
            <div class="page-content__inner">
                <div class="boxes">
                    <div class="box">{{content}}</div>
                    <div class="box">{{content}}</div>
                </div>
            <div class="actionbar"></div>
        </div>
    </main> 
</div>
```

css

```
.l-page{
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.page-header{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.page-content{
  flex: 1;
  background-color: wheat;
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

.page-content__inner{
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.boxes{
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.box{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1;
}

.box+.box{
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.actionbar{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

**update**
The height of the actionbar can vary. It's just set with 50px to simplify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're boxes seems to grow more than the allowed height - if you set it's size to be a max-height of 100% minus  the height of actionbar, it seems to fix the issue:

```js
const content = 'Mit Hilfe des Blindtextes kann die Verteilung des Textes auf der Seite (Layout oder Satzspiegel) sowie Lesbarkeit und Platzbedarf der verwendeten Schriftarten (Typografie) beurteilt werden. Er besteht aus einer mehr oder minder sinnlosen Folge von Wörtern, oft auch nur aus wortähnlichen Silbenfolgen. Ein bekanntes Beispiel dafür ist das „lateinische“ Lorem ipsum. Komponisten von Liedern benutzen Blindtexte beim Komponieren von Melodien und singen diese, bevor der Liedtext gedichtet wird. Andere Texte dienen dazu, die Eigenheiten der Schriftarten miteinander vergleichen zu können. In solchen Pangrammen werden möglichst alle Buchstaben und Sonderzeichen des jeweiligen sprachtypischen Alphabets bei einer möglichst geringen Gesamtlänge des Satzes beziehungsweise der Sätze verwendet. Bekannte Beispiele sind: „Franz jagt im komplett verwahrlosten Taxi quer durch Bayern.“ (bekannt aus der Schriftenanzeige von Microsoft Windows)„Falsches Üben von Xylophonmusik quält jeden größeren Zwerg.“ (bekannt aus der Schriftenanzeige von KDE)„The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog“ (englisch für „Der schnelle braune Fuchs springt über den faulen Hund“) „Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.“ (Dohlen lieben meine große Sphinx aus Quarz)„Zwölf Boxkämpfer jagen Viktor quer über den großen Sylter Deich“„Die heiße Zypernsonne quälte Max und Victoria ja böse auf dem Weg zur Küste“„Fix Schwyz! quäkt Jürgen blöd vom Paß“ – dieser Satz ist das einzige im Deutschen bekannte echte Pangramm, das jeden Buchstaben, einschließlich der Umlaute und des ß, genau einmal enthält (nach der neuen Rechtschreibung wird allerdings „Pass“ mit „ss“ geschrieben)„Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.“ - eine Art verballhorntes Latein. Es geht allerdings auch noch kürzer: Schriftmusterwörter wie „Hamburgefonts“ stellen den Charakter einer Schrift dar, ohne das ganze Alphabet zu verwenden. Mit Hilfe des Blindtextes kann die Verteilung des Textes auf der Seite (Layout oder Satzspiegel) sowie Lesbarkeit und Platzbedarf der verwendeten Schriftarten (Typografie) beurteilt werden. Er besteht aus einer mehr oder minder sinnlosen Folge von Wörtern, oft auch nur aus wortähnlichen Silbenfolgen. Ein bekanntes Beispiel dafür ist das „lateinische“ Lorem ipsum. Komponisten von Liedern benutzen Blindtexte beim Komponieren von Melodien und singen diese, bevor der Liedtext gedichtet wird. Andere Texte dienen dazu, die Eigenheiten der Schriftarten miteinander vergleichen zu können. In solchen Pangrammen werden möglichst alle Buchstaben und Sonderzeichen des jeweiligen sprachtypischen Alphabets bei einer möglichst geringen Gesamtlänge des Satzes beziehungsweise der Sätze verwendet. Bekannte Beispiele sind:';

document.querySelectorAll('.ff')[0].innerHTML = content;
document.querySelectorAll('.box')[1].innerHTML = content;
document.querySelectorAll('.box')[1].innerHTML += content;
document.querySelectorAll('.box')[1].innerHTML += content;
```

```css
.l-page{
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ff{
  min-height:0;
}

.page-header{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.page-content{
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: wheat;
  padding: 50px;
  position:relative;
}

.page-content__inner{
  position:absolute;
  left:50px;
  right:50px;
  top:50px; 
  bottom:50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.boxes {
  flex-grow:1;
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction:row;
  max-height: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.box{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.box+.box{
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.actionbar{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="l-page">
  <header class="page-header"></header>
  <main class="page-content">
    <div class="page-content__inner">
      <div class="boxes">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="ff"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="actionbar"></div>
    </div>
  </main> 
</div>
```

As per comments - no fixed height for actionbar - seems like you need to set a min and max-height:

[Updated Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oEKrLJ)

Comment: Yes that works, but only if the actionbar have a fixed height, but in may case the height of the actionbar can vary. I updated this in my question.

Comment: Your question has not been edited and the actionbar has a fixed height?

Comment: thanks, for your effort ;) in your codepen  the solution is no to set the min- max-height. it works also without it. Set the parent element position absolute with top right... gives the whole container a height and that works ;)

Comment: If you remove the min and max heights, it doesn't work in firefox?

Comment: It works in FF without min- and max-height, when i use the position: absolute with top left right & bottom, to give the container dimensions. I only wanted to mention it, because you wrote 'As per comments - no fixed height for actionbar - seems like you need to set a min and max-height'